# How to create Heikin Ashi Candles from scratch?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to build heikin ashi candle by myself. Based on the definition
[image]

I am doing it like:

```
ha_close = (open + high + low + close)/4
ha_high = math.max(open , high, low , close)
ha_low = math.min(open , high, low , close)
var float ha_open = na
ha_open := na(ha_open[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
plotcandle(ha_open, ha_high, ha_low, ha_close, title='Title', color = ha_open < ha_close ? color.rgb(161, 143, 239) : color.rgb(120, 134, 122, 40), wickcolor=ha_open < ha_close ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40),bordercolor = ha_open < ha_close ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40) )
```

The tricky part is `ha_open` and I am not sure how to do it...

Also, this the current version is not accurate, because use the HA candle of TV or if I do the following

```
[closeh,openh,lowh,highh] = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [close,open,low,high])

plotcandle(openh, highh, lowh, closeh, title='Title', color = openh < closeh ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40), wickcolor=openh < closeh ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40),bordercolor = openh < closeh ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40) )
```

the charts dont match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is almost correct. You need to use the calculated open and close prices in high and low calculations.

Also, for the high and low calculations, you need to pass three variables and not four.

Here is the code for you.

I have also added a test code that compares the calculated values with the results from the `security()` call. It should change the background color to red if there is any mismatch. I did not see any :)

```
//@version=5
indicator("HA", overlay=true)

var float ha_open = na
ha_close = (open + high + low + close)/4
ha_open := na(ha_open[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
ha_high = math.max(ha_open , high, ha_close)
ha_low = math.min(ha_open , low , ha_close)

[closeh,openh,lowh,highh] = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [close,open,low,high])

is_not_correct = (ha_close != closeh) or (ha_open != openh) or (ha_high != highh) or (ha_low != lowh)

bgcolor(is_not_correct ? color.red : na)

plotcandle(ha_open, ha_high, ha_low, ha_close, title='Title', color = ha_open < ha_close ? color.rgb(161, 143, 239) : color.rgb(120, 134, 122, 40), wickcolor=ha_open < ha_close ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40),bordercolor = ha_open < ha_close ? color.navy : color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 40) )
```

Comment: A follow up question: on the chart everything is good and it behave as expected. However, when I try to do replay I see weird mismatches, do you know why?

Comment: Which ticker and timeframe are you testing this on?

Comment: 10m in ES! https://www.tradingview.com/x/cr5JND4z/
Both ETH and RTH have this issue.

Comment: update, it seems that this issue is mainly happens on future indexes. on stocks and crypto works fine.